# Data Fusion Executing More Than 5 Pipelines At The Same Time

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

This is really weird since I didn't see any information about this and I still can't find anything. When I try to run more than 5 pipelines at once, the 6th one gets 'REJECTED' and does not start. It says that only 5 pipelines can be provisioned at the same time. Anyone knows anything about this maybe it is happening because I am using Developer version?

Comment: Looks like your pipeline launches are getting throttled by flow control - https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/concepts/flow-control

Comment: Hmm I see. So it seems like there is no way to 'provision' more than 5 pipelines at the same time.